# How to delete a user completely using esign REST API

Tags: docusignapi

Need to completely erase a user record in the account after being closed.

After successfully deleted a user according to the API reference, the user is still visible in DocuSign. Since the documentation says the user is never deleted, need to know if there is a way to delete completely or if is not possible.
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/users/users/delete

```
DELETE https://NA3.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/<account_id>/users
Request Body: {"users":[{"userId"=>"<user_id>"}]}
Response Body: {"users":[{"userId"=>"<user_id>", "uri":"/users/<user_id>", "userStatus"=>"closed"}]}
```

After successful deletion, the user is still visible in DocuSign. Need to know if there is an end point to really delete a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot actually delete a user. per https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Users/Users/delete:
"Closes one or more user records in the account. Users are never deleted from an account, but closing a user prevents them from using account functions."
This is for various reasons including security, legality and ability to refer to old documents by users who were deleted.